# How to Determine Signal Voltage

Tags: voltage, audio, voltage-measurement

How is a non-sinusoidal (I realize however all signals can be broken up into combos of sinusoidal waveforms) voltage measured? Let's say an interested party plays a standard shape G-chord on their guitar and stores the signal in the oscilloscope. Would the signal "voltage" be measured from peak to peak? Would it be an average of the signal overall across some timeframe? Is there some other trick to knowing the overall voltage? Is this how I should be going about it at all? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the purpose, or what you are measuring it for.

In a digital audio recording system, you don't want to clip the peaks, so you need to measure the peak amplitude.

In analog tape systems and LP recordings, the average loudness mattered (and some distortion on peaks was tolerated) so a time-averaged measure of the amplitude was preferred, with rise and fall times in the 0.1 second to a few seconds was preferred : this was known as the ["VU metering"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VU_meter) system, where Volume Units were shown in dB referenced to a nominal loudness, and peaks a few dB above that were tolerated.

[image]

Analog radio broadcasting has limitations on peak power somewhat similar to digital; broadcasters adopted several different forms of ["Peak Program metering"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_programme_meter) or PPMs.

The BBC for example developed their PPM sometime around WW2, with carefully calibrated accuracy and well defined rise and fall times, so that a peak of 5 milliseconds read 4dB below its true level, and the reading would decay by 24dB in 2.4 seconds.

The display was as easy to read as possible : white numbers 1 to 7 on a black background, representing 4dB per step (later, 6dB between 1 and 2, 4dB per other step. Nominal "0dB" was step 4, (representing a line level of 1 mW into 600 ohms, or 0.775Vrms), with +8dB headroom permitted (transmitters are lined up to 100% modulation at +8dB), so engineers would aim for 4 most of the time, and the catchphrase was "peak to 6" for the loud bits.

[image]

This is standardised as the EBU Type II PPM, IEC60268-10 Type II. Most other European broadcasters use a similar standard, (Type I) with a scale reading in dB.
(Photos from linked articles)

So, if you were at the Maida Vale studios recording a [Peel Session](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Peel%20Sessions) for the legendary John Peel Show, your G chord would "peak to 6" in the guitar solo, or be faded down to 4 to make room for the drums and vocals.

Answer (score 1):

> *Would the signal "voltage" be measured from peak to peak?*

You can measure pk-to-pk for sure and that would be useful for determining if clipping might occur in an amplifier stage. But, generally, we are probably most most inclined to want the RMS value (root-mean-squared) because the RMS voltage of a complex waveform equates to how much power it can generate in a resistor. In fact, the RMS value of any waveform is the DC voltage that produces a certain power in a load resistor. In other words 1 volt RMS produces the same heat as 1 volt DC for the same load resistor.

> *Would it be an average of the signal overall across some timeframe?*

An average of a signal from a guitar (for instance) from beginning of the chord being played to the final end of the signal would be zero. This is because the signal is AC and has equal weight in the positive parts of the waveform as the negative parts of the waveform. Hence the positive parts cancel the negative parts when averaging. No, not a useful signal measure I would say.

RMS is the most commonly IMHO.

Comment: Good point about the signal average. Exactly right. Perhaps I should have said the average of the positive or negative half of the signal, assuming they are symmetrical. And then multiplying by 2. I can see how RMS would be useful. What would the "signal level" be? The RMS of the peak to peak value? At what point of the signal should the RMS value be measured?

Comment: `What would the "signal level" be? ` - I have no idea without looking at a specific signal. `The RMS of the peak to peak value?` - The RMS of the p-p value is a nonsensical value. `At what point of the signal should the RMS value be measured?` - at whatever point (actually a spread of points) you want @DavidGraham